# How to properly make a user class with a session

Tags: php, object-oriented, session

So I am working on a LMS project and I have a User class that will handle everything about the user such as registration, login, showing list of courses that they are subscribed to, etc.

**User.class.php**

```
class User {
    protected $_firstName;
    protected $_lastName;
    protected $_email;
    protected $_username;
    protected $_password;
    protected $_createdOn;
    protected $_userLevel;
    protected $_salt = '}$YY lGC6&wib=w{dpqgzXv>{)A3w)5@mi`/Q7HK|/GwZ6)K<4I~Ey-bQ';

    public function getFirstName() { return $this->_firstName; }

    public function setFirstName($value) { 
            $this->_firstName = $value;
            if (empty($value)) {
                    setError('firstName', 'Enter your first name.');
            } else if (strlen($value) < 2) {
                    setError('firstName', 'The name you provided is too short.');
            } else if (!ctype_alpha(str_replace(array('-',' '), '', $value))) {
                    setError('firstName', 'The name you provided can only contain letters.');
            }
    }

    public function getLastName() { return $this->_lastName; }

    public function setLastName($value) { 
            $this->_lastName = $value;
            if (empty($value)) {
                    setError('lastName', 'Enter your last name.');
            } else if (strlen($value) < 2) {
                    setError('lastName', 'The name you provided is too short.');
            } else if (!ctype_alpha(str_replace(array('-',' '), '', $value))) {
                    setError('lastName', 'The name you provided can only contain letters.');
            }
    }

    public function getEmail() { return $this->_email; }

    public function setEmail($value) {
            $this->_email = $value;
            $pattern = '!^.{1,}@.{2,}$!i';
            if (empty($value)) {
                    setError('email', 'Enter your email.');
            } else if (substr_count($value, '@') != 1 and !preg_match($pattern, $value)) {
                    setError('email', 'The email you provided is not valid.');
            }
    }

    public function getUsername() { return $this->_username; }

    public function setUsername($value) { 
            $this->_username = strtolower($value);
            if (empty($value)) {
                    setError('username', 'Enter your username.');
            } else if (strlen($value) < 6) {
                    setError('username', 'The username you provided must have at least 6 characters.');
            } else if (!ctype_alnum(str_replace('_', '', $value))) {
                    setError('username', 'The username you provided can only contain letters, numbers, and underscores.');
            }
    }

    public function getPassword() { return $this->_password; }

    public function setPassword($value) { 
            $this->_password = $value;
            if (empty($value)) {
                    setError('password', 'Enter a password.');
            } else if (strlen($value) < 6) {
                    setError('password', 'The password you provided must have at least 6 characters.');
            }
    }

    public function setConfirmPassword($value) {
            if (empty($value)) {
                    setError('confirmPassword', 'Re-enter your password again.');
            } else if ($this->_password != $value) {
                    setError('confirmPassword', 'This does not match your password.');
            }
    }

    private function _encrypt($value) {
            return sha1(md5($this->_salt.md5($value)));
    }

    public function register() {
            if (!hasErrors()) {
                    try {
                            $core = Core::getInstance();
                            $sth = $core->dbh->prepare(<<<SQL
INSERT IGNORE INTO `users` SET 
`first_name` = :first_name, `last_name` = :last_name, `email` = LOWER(:email), 
`username` = LOWER(:username), `password` = :password, 
`created_on` = NOW()
SQL
                            );
                            $sth->bindValue(':first_name', propercase($this->_firstName), PDO::PARAM_STR);
                            $sth->bindValue(':last_name', propercase($this->_lastName), PDO::PARAM_STR);
                            $sth->bindValue(':email', $this->_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                            $sth->bindValue(':username', $this->_username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                            $sth->bindValue(':password', $this->_encrypt($this->_password), PDO::PARAM_STR);
                            $sth->execute();
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                            // print $e->getMessage();
                    }      
            }
    }

    public function login() {
            if (!hasErrors()) {
                    try {
                            $core = Core::getInstance(); 
                            $sth = $core->dbh->prepare(<<<SQL
SELECT * 
FROM `users`
WHERE `username` = :username
LIMIT 1     
SQL
                            );
                            $sth->bindValue(':username', $this->_username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                            $sth->execute();
                            $row = $sth->fetch();
                            $sth->closeCursor();

                            if ($row and $row->password == $this->_encrypt($this->_password)) {
                                    $_SESSION['uid'] = $row->id;
                                    $_SESSION['user'] = $row->username;
                                    $_SESSION['pass'] = $row->password;
                                    $_SESSION['level'] = $row->user_level;
                            }
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                            // print $e->getMessage();
                    }
            }
    }

    private function _destroySession() {
            session_unset();
            session_destroy();
    }

    public function logout() {
            $this->_destroySession();
            redirect('index.php');
    }

    public function check() {
            if (isset($_SESSION['pass'])) {
                    try {       
                            $core = Core::getInstance(); 
                            $sth = $core->dbh->prepare(<<<SQL
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username
LIMIT 1
SQL
                            );
                            $sth->bindValue(':username', $_SESSION['user'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                            $sth->execute();
                            $row = $sth->fetch();
                            $sth->closeCursor();
                            if (!$row or $row->password != $_SESSION['pass']) {
                                    $this->logout();
                            }
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                            // print $e->getMessage();
                    }
            }
    }

    public function isLoggedIn() {
            return (isset($_SESSION['pass']));
    }

    public function getCourseSubscriptions() {
            $rows = array();
            try {
                    $core = Core::getInstance();
                    $sth = $core->dbh->prepare(<<<SQL
SELECT c.`id` AS id, c.`code` AS code, c.`name` AS name, 
IF(`u_id` IS NULL, 0, 1) AS subscribed
FROM `courses` c
LEFT JOIN `course_subscriptions` s 
ON c.id = s.`c_id` AND s.`u_id` = :u_id
ORDER BY `code`
SQL
                    );
                    $sth->bindValue(':u_id', $_SESSION['uid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $sth->execute();
                    $rows = $sth->fetchAll();
                    $sth->closeCursor();
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                    // print $e->getMessage();
            }
            return $rows;
    }

    public function addCourseSubscription($c_id) {
            try {
                    $core = Core::getInstance();
                    $sth = $core->dbh->prepare(<<<SQL
INSERT IGNORE INTO `course_subscriptions`(c_id, u_id) 
VALUES(:c_id, :u_id)
SQL
                    );
                    $sth->bindValue(':c_id', $c_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $sth->bindValue(':u_id', $_SESSION['uid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $sth->execute();
                    return true;
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                    // print $e->getMessage();
            }
            return false;
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine but I feel.. stuck with how to use this object properly with a session. Below is an example on how I am currently using my class.

**course_catalog.php**

```
$userObj = new User();
$userObj->check();
$list = $userObj->getCourseSubscriptions();
```

Any suggestions on how I can improve any of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I would split the `User` class in 2 or 3 classes `User`, `Authentication` and `Registration`. The setter error could easily become Exceptions, which you could collect in you Registration class.

At the end you will have a smaller User object you can attach to the session.

Please also check http://www.phpbuilder.com/columns/validating_php_user_sessions.php3 for some hint regarding session validation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about splitting the class. That really helped me. I don't quite understand though when you say change the setter error to Exceptions. Should I be creating a custom exception for each property that I'm trying to set e.g. throw InvalidFirstNameException()? Though, if I am calling the setters one after the other, wouldn't throwing an exception cause not all setters to be called.

Comment: I think the is something like an InvalidParameterException. You would catch this exception in you Registration class and transform them to an error message for the user.